# Pulling through restful API using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, api

Can anyone help been scratching my head about this for a while now how can I pull through this JSON feed into HTML document using jquery for e.g. I want to pull through "base_title" into a `h2` tag etc.

http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v1/us/events

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the JSON response from that server, you can parse the response and then use jQuery's `.each()` method to loop through each event.  After that it's just a matter of rendering the markup.

```
function displayEvents(events, container) {
    var allEventsMarkup = '<ul class="eventList">';
    $.each(events, function(i, event) {
        var eventMarkup = '<li class="event">';
        eventMarkup += '<h2>' + event.base_title + '</h2>';

        // ...continue to display whatever properties 
        // you care about from the event object...

        eventMarkup += '</li>';
        allEventsMarkup += eventMarkup;
    });
    allEventsMarkup += '</ul>';
    container.html(allEventsMarkup);
}

var eventListContainer = $('body');
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v1/us/events",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(response) {
    var events = JSON.parse(response);
    displayEvents(events, eventListContainer);
});
```

Note that if your server doesn't host the endpoint, you may run into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)  issues.

Comment: How would i create the HTML so renders on a web page ? Thanks for your help this is great